# The (publishing) tag and academia.SE

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, tag-management

I voted to close [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186318/is-a-corrigiendum-necessary-if-a-published-result-is-discovered-to-duplicate-an), with the justification that it is about mathematical publishing, not mathematics itself, and it would be better suited to [academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/). This seems consistent with the way we tend to handle questions which are related to mathematics or mathematicians, but which do not actually contain mathematics.

The help-center certainly makes the point that we want questions about mathematics at math.SE, but it doesn't specifically list questions about mathematical publishing as one of the types of off-topic question. So:

1. Should questions about publishing be considered off-topic, and possibly migrated to academia.SE if they're high quality?
2. If yes, what should we do about the [publishing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) tag? A glance over the recent questions for this tag suggests that many questions either have mathematical content (and other tags to match it) or have been poorly received.

Similar questions have been considered twice before:

- [Tag article-writing](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12738/tag-article-writing)
- [Moving questions to academia.SE?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4374/moving-questions-to-academia-se)

...but at that time academia.SE was still in beta.

Comment: If a question is about mathematics-specific issues in publishing then I see no problem posting such questions here. Academica can be very different depending on the specific field you work in and ASE seems best suited for general questions about academia (and the linked question is such a general question that applies to any field). That being said many good mathematicians seem to be active on ASE so questions about mathematics-specific issues often get good answers there.

Comment: Being on-topic on another SE site isn't a reason to close in and of itself. Closing the linked question seems reasonable, since it doesn't actually seem to be specific to mathematics publishing, but would probably apply roughly equally to any paper in a STEM subject.